# Observable: ANDing sources and completion

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I have a set of `IObservable<bool>`s - let's call them `sources` - and I want to AND the values of these to produce `true` if all the inputs are true:

```
sources.CombineLatest().Select(values => values.All(x => x))
```

However, if one of the sources completes while having the value of `false` (which means that all of the sources can never again be `true`) I want to signal `false` and complete.

How would I do that?

Comment: "if one of the sources completes while having the value of `false`" then you already have signaled `false` at least once and it's now all about completing, right? Or is it crucial that `false` be signaled twice in a row?

Comment: No, doesn't need to signal it twice, it just needs to complete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my take on it without publishing and the need of schedulers:

```
public static IObservable<bool> Foo(
    this IEnumerable<IObservable<bool>> sources)
{
    var projectedSources = sources.Select(source => source
        .Materialize()
        .Scan(
            new
            {
                Latest = true,
                IsCompleted = false
            },
            (tuple, notification) => new
            {
                Latest = notification.HasValue ? notification.Value : tuple.Latest,
                IsCompleted = tuple.IsCompleted || !notification.HasValue
            }));

    return projectedSources
        .CombineLatest()
        .TakeWhile(list => list.All(x => !x.IsCompleted || x.Latest))
        .Select(list => list.All(x => x.Latest))
        .DistinctUntilChanged();
}
```

First, we materialize every source and scan through it, recording its last value and whether the source has already completed. Then, we combine the sources, taking from the result only as long all sources are either uncompleted or have a latest value of `true`. Then, we project the values of all sources to a single output value.

Note: You might want to start your sources with a value of `true` (like in the above solution). Experiment with it.

Comment: You can add `.StartWith(true)` before `Materialize()` to enforce all sources starting with a value.

Comment: Also, small compiler error. `e.Latest` does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

I think this does it:

```
public static IObservable<bool> Foo(
    this IEnumerable<IObservable<bool>> sources)
{                       
    var sourceArray = sources.Select(s => s.Publish().RefCount()).ToArray();

    var terminator = sourceArray
        .ToObservable(Scheduler.Default)
        .SelectMany(x => x.StartWith(true).LastAsync().Where(y => y == false));

    var result = sourceArray
        .CombineLatest(values => values.All(x => x))
        .DistinctUntilChanged()
        .TakeUntil(terminator);

    return result; 
}
```

There's a bit of publishing going on to prevent side effects, but otherwise the key is `terminator` which watches for a stream with a last value of false.

Comment: Yes! That did it, thank you - it's obvious now I see the answer.

Comment: I'm not convinced about this one. You could easily get into an race-condition between subscribing in `terminator` and `CombineLatest`. For example, this yields `Side effect!` twice:             `Foo(new[] {
                 Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50)).Select(x => true)
            ,Observable.Create<Boolean>(o => {
                Console.WriteLine("Side effect!");
                o.OnCompleted(); 
                return Disposable.Empty; 
            }) 
            }).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);`

Comment: Also, this testcase should yield `true, false, true, false ...` but gives nothing: `Foo(new[] {
              Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50)).Select(x =>  (x % 2) == 0)
            , Observable.Return(true)
            }).Subscribe(Console.WriteLine); `

Comment: @Dorus, does sending `ToObservable()` to a scheduler fix your test case?

Comment: @JamesWorld It solves the second example, not the first one with the double `Side effect!`. You can get around that by wrapping the entire thing in an `Observable.Create`, and not use `RefCount`, but `Connect` the array after you initialized both `terminator` and `result`.